# React doesn't update component after setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

I have a problem with updating component in React. My `Autocomplete` component has its `defaultValue` property which is linked to `this.state.tags`. At the time of executing `render()` method the `this.state.tags` array is not yet fetched, so it's set empty in the component. When `this.state.tags` array is set to it's fetched value the `Autocomplete` is not updated by the React.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    tags:[],
    all_tags:[{tag: "init"}]
  };
}
```

```
componentDidMount() {

axios.post('http://localhost:1234/api/issue/getIssueById', {id: this.props.match.params.id}, { withCredentials: true })
  .then(res=>{
  var arr = [];
  res.data.tags.forEach(x=>{
      arr.push({tag: x});
  });
  this.setState((state,props)=>{return {tags: arr}});
})
.catch((e)=>{console.log(e)});
}
```

```
render() {

return (
  <Fragment>
      <Autocomplete
             multiple
             defaultValue={this.state.tags[0]}
             onChange={(event, value) => console.log(value)}
             id="tags-standard"
             options={this.state.all_tags}
             getOptionLabel={option => option.tag}
             renderInput={params => (
               <TextField
                 {...params}
                 variant="standard"
                 label="Multiple values"
                 placeholder="Favorites"
                 fullWidth
               />
             )}
           />
      </Fragment>
    );
}
```

**Edit:** 
If I put this inside `render()`:

```
    setTimeout(()=>{
      console.log("this.state.tags: ", this.state.tags);
    }, 1000);
```

`this.state.tags` is set correctly.

Comment: If you add `{JSON.stringify(this.state)}` within your `<Fragment>`, do you see the tags array(s) changing as you expect? If so, it might be an issue/bug in the autocomplete component you use.

Comment: @AKX Yes I see the array I expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First,  you need to use `this.state.tags` as options in Autocomplete.

Second your usage of setState seems problematic.

And lastly, if you need to populate all the tags in the render, you need to use `value` property of the [Autocomplete](https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete) component.

```
import React, { Fragment, Component } from "react";
import { fetchTags } from "./fakeApi";
import Autocomplete from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      tags: [],
      selectedTags: [],
      all_tags: [{ tag: "init" }]
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetchTags()
      .then(res => {
       let allTags = res.data.tags.map(el => ({ tag: el }));
        this.setState({
          tags: allTags,
          selectedTags: allTags
        });
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  }
  onChange = value => {
      this.setState({
        selectedTags: value
      })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Autocomplete
          multiple
          value={this.state.selectedTags}
          onChange={(event, value) => this.onChange(value)}
          id="tags-standard"
          options={this.state.tags}
          getOptionLabel={option => option.tag}
          renderInput={params => (
            <TextField
              {...params}
              variant="standard"
              label="Multiple values"
              placeholder="Favorites"
              fullWidth
            />
          )}
        />
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Working [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/twilight-firefly-c3ciq) sample with a fake api.

Comment: Well, the code it the Codesandbox you've provided doesn't work as expected. Chips/tags schould be populated at the initial render. See "Multiple values" section here: https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/ . Here I forked your sandbox and modified to demonstrate where is the problem: https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-bhaskara-qmk5i

Comment: @Kristopher you need to use value property if you want to populate the tags. See the updated answer and codesandbox please.

Comment: @Kristopher I also corrected the onChange functionality. I appreciate if you can also upvote.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `options={this.state.all_tags}` and in the `componentDidMount` you are updating `tags` field in the state. I think there is the issue.

Comment: I don't think so. `options` work fine. I've an issue with `defaultValue`which is not updating.

Comment: Can you create any sandbox with your code? I don't understand how your component can work (the options) if the code is like in the question.